# Redirect a domain request to a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a domain to a subfolder within the same server. Let me break it down on topics:

1. I have the domain domain.com
2. I created the subdomain subdomain.domain.com
3. I redirected (A record) subdomain.domain.com to the domain.com server's IP address
4. I am trying to create a htaccess file that redirects every user that comes from subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/aaa

I can't figure out how though. I suppose I need to create a rewriting rule but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

To Redirect `sub.example.com` to `example.com/folder` you can use the following Rule in your `/public_html/. htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/folder/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```